# The createUploadSession is returning an uploadurl longer than 2000 chars which is breaking the limit in IE and Edge

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Because of the access_token and proof_token url params the returned upload url is more than 2000 chars. This is causing the preflight OPTIONS request of an ajax PUT to abort in Internet Explorer and Edge. Works fine in Chrome. Please provide some other option of providing the access_token and proof_token (i.e. in the header).

I'm accessing the drive by id and possibly my token is extra long

Repro: jsfiddle.net/qwp5vocc/7

Comment: Please post the code you are using to do this, and the error messages you are getting. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in a way to help us to help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qwp5vocc/7/

Comment: I meant to post the code here by editing your original question. We need the actual error message too

Comment: What do you mean? Should I put the jsfiddle in the question itself? Done. No error message. It is just aborting on the preflight in the browser.